# Transact-SQL: Display two SUM() from differents tables?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sum

This is a simplified exemple of what I want :

**Table 1 :**

```
CODE | VALUE
A    | 10
A    | 20
B    | 10
C    | 20
```

**Table 2 :**

```
CODE | VALUE2
A    | 25
B    | 10
B    | 10
D    | 20
```

And this is what I want :

```
CODE | SUM(VALUE) | SUM(VALUE2)
A    | 30         | 25
B    | 10         | 20
C    | 20         | NULL
D    | NULL       | 20
```

I tried naively :

```
SELECT T1.CODE, SUM(VALUE), SUM(VALUE2)
FROM table1 T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
GROUP BY T.CODE
```

But the results are wrong and I don't know what to do... Someone can explain me how to resolve this problem and create a proper query ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be something like this?

```
select code, sum(v1), sum(v2)
  from (select code, value v1, null v2
          from table1
        union
        select code, null v1, value2 v2
          from table2)
 group by code
```